# Managed Package: Feature Parameters - Advanced Usage

Tags: managed-package, feature-management, lmo, fma

In our managed package we are planning to use Feature Parameters (in particular LMO to Subscriber, boolean) to be able to enable/disable feature in subscribers orgs right from LMO/FMA.

After reading through documentation there are still couple questions we cannot find answers about:

1. is it possible to remove feature param after major version has been
   released? We are worried about the restriction re having 25 feature
   params - would we be able just to remove outdated feature params
   from previous major release and use free slots for new feature
   params in scope of next package release?
2. Is it allowed to create/remove feature params in patch org?
3. is it possible to do a mass update of value for specific feature
   param from LMO org for e.g. 10-100 subscribers? From what we've
   seen, feature param is linked to subscriber license in LMO org, as
   result it can be manually edited per each subscriber. But if we want
   to e.g. activate some feature for a subset of our subscribers, can
   we do so somehow from UI (e.g. like doing package push upgrade,
   where we can upgrade hundredth of subscribers at once)? Or maybe is
   it possible via some Apex snippet by querying and updating schema
   objects directly?
4. When value of 'LMO to Subscriber' feature param is updated from LMO
   org and propagated to subscriber org, is it possible to execute some
   piece of Apex code, like a Trigger for Feature Param Update in
   subscriber org? Having some sort of a scheduler/batch to check value
   of feature param every 5-10 mins in subscriber org is not a good
   solution for us. We would like to be able to create/remove some
   records and update some settings in subscriber org right away when
   feature is enabled/disabled from LMO org.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance